# What actually is a rasterizer? and is freetype part of linux OS or separate library?

Tags: linux, fonts, freetype, freetype2, rasterizer-state

I am starting a research on fonts and my target is to develop a driver module for Freetype 2 rasterizer. So for that i need to know the basics first. I have read some blogs about what restrizer basically is?

What i understood is that Font Rasterizer is basically a built in low level application on OS whose task is to convert a vector based font into bitmap font. (Not sure still confused). I want to know why we actually need font rasterizer?.

And for Freetype Rasterizer i got the concept that its a type of font rasterizer (default) low level library of linux which gets any type of a file like trutype as input and prints the file according to the style? Is it right?

I need clearification on this. How can i learn about Freetype as there official website documentaiton is too abstract.

Answer (score 0):

A rasterizer transforms vector (outline) shapes (glyphs) contained in a font file in bitmap images. Since computer screens have a very low pixel density that means distorting shapes to adapt them to a very small number of pixels, finding the best compromise between sharpness, fidelity to the original design, and consistency.

A rasterizer is insufficient by itself to display anything but the most trivial strings of text. Any serious text rendering needs to position those images in relation to one another according to complex Opentype rules, which requires a shaper such as [harfbuzz-ng](http://harfbuzz.org/).

The following articles are a bit dated, they do not represent the current state of various text renderers (all the stack from rasterizer to shaper), but they do include many examples of the operations needed to transform font glyphs in text and the kind of problems that needs to be dealt with :

- [text is not a string of letters](http://www.unifont.org/textlayout/TheBigPicture.pdf)
- [old overview of Linux text stack](http://behdad.org/text/)
- [pango and grid-fitting](https://people.redhat.com/otaylor/grid-fitting/)
- [agg on hinting](http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/index.html)
- [newer challenges](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wpzgGMqXgit6FBVaO76epnnFC_rQPdVKswrDQWyqO1M/edit)

Comment: Freetype is the penultimate rasterizer, with all limitations detailed above. Linux systems being quite modular component limits are easier to identify than on other systems.